# Compiled software won't open unless given administrative permissions?

Tags: c#, codedom

I've compiled a program via CodeDOM compiler, and it refuses to open unless it's given administrative permissions, why is this? Is it something in my code? Is it something that happens often?

```
        //rkey.SetValue("program", Application.ExecutablePath);
        this.txtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 25);
        this.wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 65);

        this.txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 20);
        this.wb.Size = GetScreen().Size;
        this.btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 25);

        this.btn.Text = "Check Key";
        btn.Click += btn_Click;

        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
        this.Controls.Add(wb);

        wb.Navigate("{SURV_URL}");

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; 

        MessageBox.Show("{MSG_DESC}", "{MSG_TITLE}");
```

It compiles perfectly fine, but I'm unable to run it without admin permissions, when I try to run, it doesn't even show the program at all, it just refuses to run and doesn't give me an error message, but if I click run as Admin, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to write to a regestry key. That is only possible in certain location when not running as administrator.

Reading however is allowed pretty much anywhere.

If you absolutely have to store info in the registry I suggest you look into where a user has write permission. Sadly I don't know this by heart so you have to find that out yourself. :-(